# Cannot read property 'caseSensitive' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typeerror

I created a simple code and I don't know what's going on because code is correct as far as I know. But it's still giving me this case sensitive error.

**App.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const data = require('./routes/data.js');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const app=express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(data.route);
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/home.html'));
});
app.listen(3000)
```

**Data.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/add-product', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/add-product.html'));
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'caseSensitive' of undefined
    at route (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:495:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\node practrice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
```

Comment: `app.use(data.route);` -> `app.use(data);`

Comment: ohhh man i thought i am using exports.routers=router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your app.js file like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const data = require('./routes/data.js');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const app=express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(data);
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/home.html'));
});
app.listen(3000)
```

the mistake was in:

```
app.use(data.route);
```

it must be like this:

```
app.use(data);
```